# Find using :has_many associations and multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application, Users view Pins which I store in a separate associations table called View. The table has an ID, a pin_id, a user_id and a rank. I would like to find Pins which meet certain criteria which the user has not seen. I am using Rails 3.2.13.

Here are my model associations:

```
class Pin
has_many :views
has_many :users, :through => :views

class View
belongs_to :pin
belongs_to :user

class User
has_many :pins
has_many :views  
has_many :pins, :through => :views
```

Right now I am doing this, which works:

**pins_controller.rb**

```
b = TRUE
sex = current_user.sex
views = current_user.views
seen = views.map(&:pin_id)
@pins = Pin.find(:first, :conditions => ["sex = ? AND active = ? AND id not in (?)", sex, b, seen])
```

I thought it would be more elegant to use a join to pull the objects using a single database query. However, I cannot get this to work. I have read a bunch of different SO articles, but I have not been able to reproduce the above using a single query. Am I correct in thinking the above is roundabout and that there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just join up `pins` to `view` and `view` to `users`.  I think the below will work, although would need the specific details on the `view` to `users` association:

```
Pin.joins(:views => :user).where("views.sex = ? and views.active = ? and users.id not in (?)", current_user.sex, true, [current_user.id])
```

Comment: Actually, I get this error `Association named 'view' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: Updated - I had originally thought a `Pin` had only 1 `View`.  Should be `:views`.

Comment: Can you post the resulting SQL?  And, can you also try eliminating some of the conditions in the where clause to see which one is eliminating all of the records?

Comment: When I ran .explain on the above query I got this error: `Association named 'users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?` I will try removing conditions to see it the problem persists.

Comment: The relationship b/w view and users would dictate whether it should be `users` or `user`.  Does a view `belongs_to` or `has_many` `users`?

Comment: I updated the question including the User associations.

Answer (score 0):

Try squeel its wounderful and more better than normal active Record query methods and give you more powerful features

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel

http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel

Comment: Propose a solution to the problem with squeel vs. just links.  It will be more helpful to the person asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Pin.joins(:views).where(sex: sex, active: b).
  merge(View.where(View.arel_table[:user_id].not_eq(current_user.id))).first
```

Comment: This also returns @pins as nil.

Comment: I just came across a similar problem in my own code so I've changed my answer to how I've currently implemented it, hope it works for you

Comment: Just realised this answer doesn't take into account Pins that have no views, so probably isn't that useful